# Filtrar un listado según un parámetro en Angular/ IONIC 4

Tags: json, angular, ionic4

Tengo esta función que me devuelve un listado de pokemons proveniente de una URL JSON de pokeapi. Necesito filtrar esta función para que me muestre los de un tipo determinado que traigo con la variable dataPoke. La variable me llega con el valor correcto pero no sé cómo darle salida filtrada y que me muestre solamente los pokemon del tipo dataPoke.
Los datos me llegan de https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon
                        https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3

```
              listadoPokemonFiltrado(salida = 0,dataPoke) {
                console.log("datos recibidos: ", dataPoke);
                return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/pokemon?salida=${salida}`)
                  .pipe(
                    map(result => { return result['results'];}),
                    map(pokemon => {
                      return pokemon.map((arreglo, index) => {
                            arreglo.image = this.obtenerImagen(salida + index + 1);
                            arreglo.pokeIndex = salida + index + 1; 
                            arreglo.type = this.obtenerTypo(dataPoke);
                            arreglo.pokeIndex = arreglo.type;
                            return arreglo;
                      });
                    })
                  );
              }
              obtenerImagen(index) {
                return `${this.imageUrl}${index}.png`;
              }

              obtenerTypo(index) {
                return `${this.baseUrlTypes}/${index}`;
              }
```